# Power two rpi4 using a power supply with 5v 6a output?

Tags: pi-4, power

Maybe a dummy question:
Can I power two rpi4 using a single power supply with 5v 6a output?
Would this still be delivering 5v 3a ti each board ?

Thx Nuno

Comment: `Would this still be delivering 5v 3a ti each board ?` ... no ... it would supply 5 V ... the current drawn by each device would depend on the work that each device is doing

Answer (score 1):

> Can I power two rpi4 using a single power supply with 5v 6a output? Would this still be delivering 5v 3a ti each board ?

> I was wondering is if the pi would get sufficient amps ?

Yes to the first, and yes to the second.

An RPi 4B won't draw more than 3 amps. Therefore, 2 of them won't draw more than 6 amps. Your only concern will be the voltage drop between the power supply output terminals, and the USB connector on your RPis. Choose cabling with the largest gauge wire you can find: 18-20 AWG if you can find it. And keep your cabling as short as possible - longer cable runs will have larger voltage drops.

Answer (score 0):

"Can I power two rpi4 using a single power supply" Yes (if it is a good quality supply) - I use a 5V 10A supply to run several Pi. NOTE very many of the available PS have very poor voltage regulation.

"Would this still be delivering 5v 3a ti each board ?" - you do not understand electrical theory; each Pi will only draw the current it requires, regardles of the PSU rating.

Comment: Thx, I agree that I don't fully get these points on power supply :)
I understand that the pi will only take the amps it needs, what I was wondering is if the pi would get sufficient amps available. I ask this because I had issues in the past with a power supply outputing 5V but not sufficient current to make the pi-4 work properly. Nuno